# #define URL as string in each .m file?

Tags: objective-c, string, url, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I'm still trying to learn Objective-C and have an app that downloads documents from a web server.
The documents are in ten, pre-defined folders and I have separate classes for each category

The way I'm accessing the files currently is, at the top of each .m file, I define the URL to the parent folder as a string, the subfolder as a separate string:

```
#define WEBHOST @"http://webserverURL/mainfolder"
#define FOLDER @"subfolderName"
```

then concatenate them:

```
NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", WEBHOST, FOLDER];
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathString];
NSData *documentsHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:documentsDirectoryURL];
```

I then parse the HTML with `hpple` and process as needed. I'm not sure if this is a particularly efficient technique and but it seems to do what I need. 
However, it seems a bit messy and I imagine I'm missing some simpler or more efficient way of achieving this.

My question: is this a reasonable way of doing this or am I committing the typical newbie crime of making things more complicated and messy than they need to be?

Comment: If WEBHOST is the same in each .m file, put its definition in a .h instead and import it.  That way, if it ever changes, you have one line to modify instead of ten.

Comment: Ah - of course. That I should have known about but had overlooked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, for one you could do the following:

```
#define WEBHOST @"http://webserverURL/mainfolder"
#define FOLDER WEBHOST @"/subfolderName"
```

And it should concatenate the webhost name to the folder name. Might save a line of code.

Comment: I'd also at least suggest: put the Webhost-definition into the pch-file, so you don't need to redefine it in every .m file.

Comment: Don't you concatenate Objective-C string literals using: `@"first bit" "second bit"`?

Comment: Not sure but I'm away to try.... OK, it generates an X-Code warning: "Format string is not a string Literal (potentially insecure)" ... but yes, it does work. 
Thanks again, I've picked up a couple of nice little tricks here.

Comment: _@Robert:_ Are you sure you use the Objective-C string notation (starting with `@`) instead of the C notation?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine, but I would suggest putting all the definitions into a single header file and including that.  You must be redefining `WEBHOST` which can lead to errors:

urldefs.h:

```
#define WEBHOST @"http://webserverURL/mainfolder"
#define SUBFOLDER1 @"subfolder1Name"
...
#define SUBFOLDER2 @"subfolder2Name"
#define SUBFOLDERn @"subfoldernName"
```

Comment: Thanks.
Would this mean creating a new NSObject file named urldefs, put the definitions in the urldefs.h file, import where needed and delete the urldefs.m file?

Comment: @Robert No, you can create a new header file on its own.